# Html Email outlook responsive

Tags: html, css, outlook, responsive-design, html-email

I'm trying to create Html email, in other email clients my layout looks great and responsive but when I check in outlook I have just one column instead of two columns, I tried to do a conditional statement for Microsoft Outlook, but no result, I get only one column, here is my code HTML, what I'm doing wrong, please?

```
/* styling */
  .two-col{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 0;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 0;
    }

    .col{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 300px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .padding{
        padding: 25px;
    }

    .content{
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: left;
    }
<tr>
    <td>
        <table role="presentation" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="two-col">
                    <!--[if mso]>
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600">
                            <tr>
                            <td  width="300">
                            <![endif]-->
                    <table role="presentation" class="col">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="padding">
                                <table class="content">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Devibtissam/emailHtmlImgs/master/img/handsPinch.png" alt="Hands Pinch">

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <h2>
                                                Customize this email template!
                                            </h2>
                                            <p style="line-height: 24px;">
                                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Elementum mattis nisi mauris pharetra ullamcorper. 
                                            </p>
                                            <a href="#" role="button"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Devibtissam/emailHtmlImgs/master/img/Button.png" alt="Try it now"></a>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                           
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                     <!--[if mso]>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <![endif]-->
                     <!--[if mso]>
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600">
                            <tr>
                            <td  width="300">
                            <![endif]-->
                    <table role="presentation" class="col">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="padding">
                            <table class="content">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Devibtissam/emailHtmlImgs/master/img/handsGive.png" alt="Hands Give">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr >
                                    <td>
                                        <h2>Customize this email template!</h2>
                                        <p style="line-height: 24px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Elementum mattis nisi mauris pharetra ullamcorper.</p>
                                        <a href="#" role="button"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Devibtissam/emailHtmlImgs/master/img/Button.png" alt="Try it now"></a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--[if mso]>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                     <!--[if mso]>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

The columns are probably just-so-slightly larger than 300 each since you have not zeroed every `<table>` (e.g. `<table role="presentation" class="col">`)

Ensure every table has minimally the following: `<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">`